# Xcode Cocoa text field to equal file path

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, cocoa

How can I have the top text field be equal to the path selected by the user?  I'm fairly new to Xcode so any help would be appreciated.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBAction func browseDMF(sender: NSOpenPanel) {

        var openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
        openPanel.canCreateDirectories = false
        openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
        openPanel.beginWithCompletionHandler { (result) -> Void in
            if result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton {

            }
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldDMF: NSTextField!
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated code:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBAction func browseDMF(sender: NSOpenPanel) {

        var openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        openPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
        openPanel.canCreateDirectories = false
        openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
        openPanel.beginWithCompletionHandler { (result) -> Void in
            if result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton {
               NSURL *pathURL = [[openPanel URLs] objectAtIndex:0];
               [textFieldDMF setStringValue:[pathURL absoluteString]];
            }
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldDMF: NSTextField!
```